# AsynchEventBus, Singleton, Threads, and Java

Tags: java, singleton, thread-synchronization, event-bus

I am new to Java and pulling some hair out on the application I'm working on. Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a client / server setup where I use QuickServer as the server. I got that up and running well. It sends and receives commands line by line with "\r"\n" so I have my client in a

```
public class CommandHandler extends Thread {
   public void run() {    
      while (connected) {
          //read and write
          if (command.equals("USERNAME")) {
             AsynchEventBusSingleton.$().postEvent(new TellParentToGiveUN())
          }

          ...
      }
}
```

My GUI freezes if I do not extend Thread so I presume the CommandHandler needs its own thread. The problem however is the AsyncEventBusSingleton.

```
public class AsyncEventBusSingleton {
private EventBus ebEventBus = null;
final static AsyncEventBusSingleton aebInstance = new AsyncEventBusSingleton();

public synchronized static AsyncEventBusSingleton $() {
    return aebInstance;
}

private AsyncEventBusSingleton() {
    ebEventBus = new AsyncEventBus(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
}

public void registerSubscriber(Object subscriber) {
    ebEventBus.register(subscriber);
}

public void unRegisterSubscriber(Object subscriber) {
    ebEventBus.unregister(subscriber);
}

public synchronized void postEvent(Object e) {
    ebEventBus.post(e);
}
}
```

When I call this class inside CommandHandler thread none of my other classes on the main thread receive the events. If I remove the "synchronized" keyword some of the events are received/repeated/an error is generated.

Everything seems to work fine if don't throw events from CommandHandler, but rather pass a reference of the class that instantiates the CommandHandler and have it call CommandHandler's methods:

```
public class ServerConnectionHandler {
   private CommandHandler commandhandler;

   public void ConnectToServer() {
        commandhandler = new CommandHandler(this);
   }

   public void dispatchServerEvent() {
     commandhandler.sendResponse("MyUN");
   }
}

public class CommandHandler extends Thread {
   private PrintWriter printWriter;
   private ServerConnectionHandler serverconnectionhandler;

   public sendResponse(String s) {
        this.printWriter.println(s);
   }

   public void run() {    
      while (connected) {
          //read and write
          if (command.equals("USERNAME")) {
             this.serverconnectionhandler.dispatchServerEvent();
          }

          ...
      }
}
```

What is the best practice for having the client listen for certain commands and dispatching events to respond?